# Difference between "process.stdout.write" and "console.log" in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between "process.stdout.write" and "console.log" in node.js?

EDIT: Using console.log for a variable showed a lot of unreadable characters while using process.stdout.write showed an object.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide an example? console.log() calls process.stdout.write with formatted output. See format() in console.js for the implementation.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

`console.log()` calls `process.stdout.write` with formatted output. See `format()` in console.js for the implementation.

Currently (v0.10.ish):

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
  this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `console.log()` appears to add a newline

Comment: `console.log()` **also** broadcasts to [debugging clients](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/). To broadcast to debugging clients without printing to stdio, you can use [`require('inspector').console.log()`](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#inspector_inspector_console).

Comment: The main difference is in the intent: `console.log`(debug/warn/whatever) is for **logging** in some **developer console** (could be browser based like chrome dev tools, or simply stdout in case of nodejs). The purpose of `process.stdout` is for the code to write to the terminal, which for console applications is typically the process output, and not just logging. The fact that they happen to relate to each other is a fortuitous accident.

Answer (score 181):

Looking at the Node docs apparently console.log is just process.stdout.write with a line-break at the end:

```
console.log = function (d) {
  process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

Source: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/process.html#process.stdout

Comment: For people coming along around later, please note that v0.3.1 was a long time ago and things have changed since then. :)

Comment: ...nope. Just looked at v0.9.9 docs and console.log is still just an alias to process.stdout.write with a linebreak.  Please do your research before commenting.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.9.9/api/process.html#process.stdout

Comment: 1) v0.9.9 is two years old 2) that documentation is incorrect, [as per v0.9.9 the format is interpolated through util](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.9.9-release/lib/console.js#L52)

Comment: Actually, it seems that that documentation has never been updated and is still around (DRY anybody?). I'll be submitting a PR to fix that, thanks for notifying me of that issue :)

Comment: Also, https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args and https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args.

Answer (score 108):

I know this is a very old question but I didn't see anybody talking about the main difference between `process.stdout.write` and `console.log` and I just want to mention it.

As [Mauvis Leford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704703/mauvis-ledford) and [TK-421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254936/tk-421) pointed out, the `console.log` adds a `line-break` character at the end of the line (`\n`) but that's not all what it does.

The code has not changed since at least `0.10.X` version and now we have a a `5.X` version.

[Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.x/lib/console.js) is the code:

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
  this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

As you can see, there is a part that says `.apply(this, arguments)` and that makes a big difference on functionality. It is easier to explain that with examples:

`process.stdout.write` has a very basic functionality, you can just write something in there, like this:

```
process.stdout.write("Hello World\n");
```

If you don't put the break line at the end you will get a weird character after your string, something like this:

```
process.stdout.write("Hello World"); //Hello World%
```

*(I think that means something like "the end of the program", so you will see it only if you `process.stdout.write` was used at the end of your file and you didn't add the break line)*

On the other hand, `console.log` can do more.

1. You can use it in the same way

   `console.log("Hello World"); //You don't need the break line here because it was already formated` and also that weird character did disappear
2. You can write more than one string

   `console.log("Hello", "World");`
3. You can make associations

   `console.log("Hello %s", "World") //Useful when "World" is inside a variable`

An that's it, that added functionality is given thanks to the `util.format.apply` part (I could talk a lot about what exactly this does but you get my point, you can read more [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.2.2-proposal/lib/util.js)).

I hope somebody find this information useful.

Comment: It would be very helpful also if you explained how to use `stdout.write` and avoid getting `%`

Comment: I solved the problem of getting `%` at the end by simply calling `process.stdout.write('\n');` at the end of my loop (if you have for example)

Comment: The `%` is just the shell's way of saying there's no newline at the end of the file.

Comment: @DaveNewton your point is important, because it means that if you are redirecting the output of your program to a file, for example, you will not get that `%` in the file

Comment: Great explain. So 2 things: console.log supports arguments joining and % at the end.

Answer (score 42):

One big difference that hasn't been mentioned is that [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) only takes strings as arguments (can also be piped streams), while [console.log](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) takes any Javascript data type.

e.g:

```
// ok
console.log(null)
console.log(undefined)
console.log('hi')
console.log(1)
console.log([1])
console.log({one:1})
console.log(true)
console.log(Symbol('mysymbol'))

// any other data type passed as param will throw a TypeError
process.stdout.write('1')

// can also pipe a readable stream (assuming `file.txt` exists)
const fs = require('fs')
fs.createReadStream('file.txt').pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Yes, effectively a pretty print.

Answer (score 35):

Another important difference in this context would with `process.stdout.clearLine()` and `process.stdout.cursorTo(0)`.

This would be useful if you want to show percentage of download or processing in the only one line. If you use clearLine(), cursorTo() with `console.log()` it doesn't work because it also append \n to the text. Just try out this example:

```js
var totalTime = 5000;
var waitInterval = totalTime / 10;
var currentInterval = 0;

function showPercentage(percentage){
    process.stdout.clearLine()
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
    console.log(`Processing ${percentage}%...` ) // Replace this line with process.stdout.write(`Processing ${percentage}%...`)
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    currentInterval += waitInterval
    showPercentage((currentInterval / totalTime) * 100)
}, waitInterval)

setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(interval)
}, totalTime + 100)
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I've just noticed something while researching this after getting help with https.request for post method. Thought I share some input to help understand.

`process.stdout.write` doesn't add a new line while `console.log` does, like others had mentioned. But there's also this which is easier to explain with examples.

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.log(d)
    });
});
```

`process.stdout.write(d);` will print the data properly without a new line. However `console.log(d)` will print a new line but the data won't show correctly, giving this `<Buffer 12 34 56...` for example.

To make `console.log(d)` show the information correctly, I would have to do this.

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    var dataQueue = "";    
    res.on("data", function (d) {
        dataQueue += d;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log(dataQueue);
    });
});
```

So basically:

- `process.stdout.write` continuously prints the information as the data being retrieved and doesn't add a new line.
- `console.log` prints the information what was obtained at the point of retrieval and adds a new line.

That's the best way I can explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The Simple Difference is:
**console.log()** methods automatically append new line character. It means if we are looping through and printing the result, each result get printed in new line.

**process.stdout.write()** methods don't append new line character. useful for printing patterns.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are great.  The following expands on the significance of the `console.log` formatting function. One of the features of formatting not yet mentioned are group levels, which *log* will honor, but *stdout* will not.

```js
console.log('Begin...')

console.group()
console.log('Line 2 (console.log)')
process.stdout.write('Line 3 (process.stdout)\n')
console.log('Line 4 (console.log)')
process.stdout.write('Line 5 (process.stdout)') // no newline
console.groupEnd()

console.log('...done')
```

**Output:**

```
Begin...
  Line 2 (console.log)
Line 3 (process.stdout)
  Line 4 (console.log)
Line 5 (process.stdout)...done
```

Notice `stdout` does not honor the console.group formatting and always writes to the beginning of the line, where as `console.log` honors the grouping and indents appropriately.

---

The same performed only with log statements (and an additional group):

```js
console.log('Begin...')

console.group()
console.log('Line 2 (console.log)')
console.log('Line 3 (console.log)')
console.log('Line 4 (console.log)')
console.log('Line 5 (console.log)')
console.group()
console.log('Line 6 (console.log)')
console.log('Line 7 (console.log)')
console.groupEnd()
console.groupEnd()

console.log('...done')
```

**Output:**

```
Begin...
  Line 2 (console.log)
  Line 3 (console.log)
  Line 4 (console.log)
  Line 5 (console.log)
    Line 6 (console.log)
    Line 7 (console.log)
...done
```

Answer (score 2):

A difference not mentioned yet is that `process.stdout` allows you to detect [backpressure](https://medium.com/@jayphelps/backpressure-explained-the-flow-of-data-through-software-2350b3e77ce7) and listen for `'drain'` events, should that be something you want to do. Either manually with `process.stdout.write()` or automatically using `stream.pipe(process.stdout)`

Imagine you want to write a massive file to stdout. If you simply tried to do this:

```js
const content = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' });
console.log(content);
```

you would have to load the entire file's contents into memory first, only then would you start writing it to stdout via `console.log(content)`. What if the file is larger than the available memory? Or you just want to be respectful of your program's memory usage.

Instead, you can do:

```js
fs.createReadStream('./example.txt').pipe(process.stdout);
```

Now your program only needs to read into memory relatively small chunks, one at a time, as stdout requests them. Then each chunk can be garbage collected after, leaving your program to use minimal memory. This one primary benefit of Node Streams.

Answer (score 1):

---

Console.log implement process.sdout.write, process.sdout.write is a buffer/stream that will directly output in your console.

According to my puglin [serverline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverline) : [`console = new Console(consoleOptions)`](https://github.com/A-312/serverline/blob/186318c906c9081926146fa7c19c3d5a9567ced6/bin/index.js#L259) you can rewrite Console class with your own [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) system.

You can see code source of console.log:

- [v14.x - lib/internal/console/constructor.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.x/lib/internal/console/constructor.js) ;
- and for old version: [v10.0.0 - lib/console.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.0.0/lib/console.js).

---

**See more :**

- [readline.createInterface](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) to make your custom behavior or use console input.

Answer (score -1):

`console.log()` adds tons of things and a new line every time you call it

`process.stdout.write()` is just plain text, no formatting

That's what I was taught at least

Answer (score -3):

For those who like [Deno](https://deno.land/), I was able to achieve this by using the following [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) in conjunction with Deno's version of `process.stdout.write`.

```
ESC[2K  clears entire line
ESC[#G  moves cursor to column #
```

Code

```
/*
    Console.log() to the same line
    Supported in Deno 1.8.1
*/

const myTextEncoder : TextEncoder = new TextEncoder();

let counter : number = 0;

while(counter < 100000) {

  // ESC[2K clears entire line
  await Deno.stdout.write(myTextEncoder.encode(`\x1b[2K`));
  // ESC[#G moves cursor to column #
  await Deno.stdout.write(myTextEncoder.encode(`\x1b[0G`));
  // OUTPUT incremented counter
  await Deno.stdout.write(myTextEncoder.encode(`COUNTER: ${counter++}`));

}
```