# Callback functions from https response not firing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am just trying to send a get request to an API.  I get a 200 response, but none of the callback functions seem to be happening, including end.
Here is the relevant section, I also have the rest of the express server up, and the server is running.

```
var https = require("https");

https.get("https://tfe-opendata.com/api/v1/stops", function(res){
    console.log("Response: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("Res: " + res);
}).on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('blah');
    console.log("data: " + data); 
    process.stdout.write(data);
}).on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('Error ' + error);
}).on('end', function(){
    console.log("End.");
});
```

It should just return JSON, and you can see the data and url are valid if you go to the [address](https://tfe-opendata.com/api/v1/stops).
None of the prints after the first callback happen.

Edit: It works if I use the full https.request method

```
var options = {
    host: 'tfe-opendata.com',
    path: '/api/v1/stops',
    method: 'GET'
}

var httpreq = https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log("data " + chunk);
    });
});

httpreq.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error: ' + e);
});

httpreq.end();
```

I still don't know why the original didn't work.

Comment: I am not really sure if you can use the path in the format of a domin `('https://tfe-opendata.com/api/v1/stops')`, perhaps you need to use an absolute path instead, something like `('/api/v1/stops')`

Comment: You can see they do it in the documentation http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't call `.on('data', )` on the result of `get`, it has to be on the `response` instance inside of the callback.

A better alternative is probably just use a library that abstracts these low level details for you (such as [request](https://github.com/request/request)).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was this way because there is https.on('error').

Answer (score 0):

You have been confused on using the API, you don't really call the `on` function on the object returned from `https.get` but instead you would do it from the `res` object provided from the callback function parameter.

The code speaks by it self, so instead of doing it like:

```
var https = require("https");

https.get("https://tfe-opendata.com/api/v1/stops", function(res) {
   console.log("Response: ", res.statusCode);
   console.log("Res: " + res);
}).on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('blah');
   console.log("data: " + data);
   process.stdout.write(data);
}).on('error', function(error) {
   console.error('Error ' + error);
}).on('end', function(){
   console.log("End.");
});
```

you should be doing it this way:

```
https.get("https://tfe-opendata.com/api/v1/stops", function(res) {
   console.log("Response: ", res.statusCode);
   console.log("Res: " + res);
   res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('blah');
      console.log("data: " + data);
      process.stdout.write(data);
   }).on('error', function(error) {
      console.error('Error ' + error);
   }).on('end', function(){
      console.log("End.");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  Small question: what is the difference between console.log and process.stdout.write ?

Comment: Refer to the answer in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js