# Node stream buffers in console.log vs process.stdout.write

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, buffer

Using **NodeJS v5.6** I created a file called `read-stream.js`:

```
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    stream = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]);

stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk);
});

stream.on('error', function(err) {
    process.stderr.write("ERROR: " + err.message + "\n");
});
```

and a data file in plain text called `target.txt`:

```
hello world
this is the second line
```

If I do `node read-stream.js target.txt` the contents of `target.txt` are printed normally on my console and all is well.

However if I switch `process.stdout.write(chunk);` with `console.log(chunk);` then the result I get is this:

```
<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 0a 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 73 65 63 6f 6e 64 20 6c 69 6e 65 0a>
```

I recently found out that by doing `console.log(chunk.toString());` the contents of my file are once again printed normally.

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4976466/178728), `console.log` is supposed to use `process.stdout.write` with the addition of a `\n` character. But what exactly is happening with encoding/decodings here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

`process.stdout` is a stream and its `write()` function only accepts strings and buffers. `chunk` is a Buffer object, `process.stdout.write` writes the bytes of data directly in your console so they appear as strings. `console.log` builds a string representation of the Buffer object before outputting it, hence the `<Buffer` at the beginning to indicate the object's type and following are the bytes of this buffer.

On a side note, `process.stdout` being a stream, you can pipe to it directly instead of reading every chunk:

```
stream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Using `pipe` is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found out what's happening:

The implementation of `console.log` in NodeJS is this:

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
    this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

However the `util.format` [function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js) of `lib/util.js` in NodeJS uses the `inspect` method on any input object which in turn: *Returns a string representation of object, which is useful for debugging.*

Thus what's happening here is that due to `util.format` "object casting", anytime that we pass an object to `console.log`, that particular object is first turned into a string representation and **then** is passed to `process.stdout.write` **as a string** and finally gets written to the terminal.

So, when we directly use `process.stdout.write` with buffer objects, `util.format` is completely skipped and each byte is directly written to terminal as `process.stdout.write` is designed to handle them directly.