# How do I encode a string of hexadecimal digits using javascript? (replicating ruby array.pack('H'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to replicate this ruby script using JavaScript and Node.js:

```sh
$ ruby -e "STDOUT.write ['e13adbea5d743c30b8ea0edd0337b924c6bd0a78'].pack('H40')"
```

There was an earlier piece where I converted `['hello'].pack('Z*')` to `Buffer.from('hello\0')`, but this other part is driving me insane.

I've found the source code for this in Ruby: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9e41a75255d15765648279629fd3134cae076398/pack.c#L426 but i don't understand C very well, let alone bit shifting in C.

I read through this Stack Exchange question and answer but still couldn't figure anything out (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings)

Any insight here would be much appreciated.

Furthermore, the best answer here would be something that I could run with `node -p` and pipe to `hexdump -C` to get the exact same output of Ruby.

i.e.

```
$ ruby -e "STDOUT.write ['e13adbea5d743c30b8ea0edd0337b924c6bd0a78'].pack('H40')" | hexdump -C

00000000  e1 3a db ea 5d 74 3c 30  b8 ea 0e dd 03 37 b9 24  |.:..]t<0.....7.$|
00000010  c6 bd 0a 78                                       |...x|
00000014
```

The closes I got was with:

```
node -p "Buffer.from('e13adbea5d743c30b8ea0edd0337b924c6bd0a78', 'hex').toString('utf8')" | hexdump -C

00000000  ef bf bd 3a ef bf bd ef  bf bd 5d 74 3c 30 ef bf  |...:......]t<0..|
00000010  bd ef bf bd 0e ef bf bd  03 37 ef bf bd 24 c6 bd  |.........7...$..|
00000020  0a 78 0a                                          |.x.|
00000023
```

Comment: Would this be an adequate re-question? "Convert a hex string to raw binary buffer". If so, what's insufficient with `from(..., 'hex')`? If not, what's insufficient with `from(...,'hex')`?

Comment: great question, how do I get node.js to output the raw binary buffer? is that possible?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/35455728/2864740 ? That is, use a stream method that accepts a Buffer directly (no to/from-string conversions).

Comment: hmm. okay let me see if I can get this to work. its very tricky to transform a buffer to a write stream but i know it is possible

Comment: Ooh its not actually as hard as i thought:

node -p "process.stdout.write(Buffer.from('e13adbea5d743c30b8ea0edd0337b924c6bd0a78', 'hex'))" | hexdump -C

Comment: Thank you! I think I have an answer to this now, need to confirm with my code though

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was that I actually was already converting a hex string to a raw binary buffer, except I wasn't realizing it because I wasn't printing it out correctly.

The working script is:

```
$ node -e "process.stdout.write(Buffer.from('e13adbea5d743c30b8ea0edd0337b924c6bd0a78', 'hex'))" | hexdump -C
```