# What else should I use for an alternative to console in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tslint

I am writing a Node.js application using the `tslint:recommended` rule set and it warns me about the usage of `console.log` in my code:

```
src/index.ts[1, 1]: Calls to 'console.log' are not allowed.
```

What else should I be using? Should I use some sort of `system.out` equivalent?

Here's my `tslint.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended"
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is stated in the [eslint doc](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console#when-not-to-use-it) about the `no-console` rule:

> #### When Not To Use It
>
> If you’re using Node.js, however, console is used to output information to the user and so is not strictly used for
>   debugging purposes. If you are developing for Node.js then you most
>   likely do not want this rule enabled.

So it is valid to deviate from the recommended ruleset here and hence I adapted my `tslint.json` to match:

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "no-console": false
    }
}
```

Comment: `false` should be `0` (at least this is the case for my version of `eslint`).

Comment: this is tslint not eslint

Comment: @jeznag That doesn't affect the reasoning on when no to use the `no-console` rule.

Comment: but what if I am just in a regular process of debugging in ReactJS, is there other way of debugging and not using the console.log

Answer (score 3):

Faster alternative to console.log:
`process.stdout.write("text");`

You will need to insert newlines yourself. Example:

`process.stdout.write("new line\n");`

[Difference between "process.stdout.write" and "console.log" in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js)