# Node.js STDOUT value not comparable with string or boolean

Tags: node.js

I am executing a shell command programatically through Node.js and the result is `true`... literally `<string> true`, but I cannot compare it neither to `boolean` nor to `string`.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} service-redis', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
   // here stdout has value "true"
   console.log(typeof stdout) // returns "string"
   console.log(stdout == 'true') // returns false
   console.log(stdout == true) // returns false
});
```

I tried converting `stdout.toString()` just in case, but the result is the same. I am confused. Any ideas?

Comment: `stdout` is a stream.

Comment: Maybe it is because of a `\n` at the end. Did you try `stdout.startsWith('true')`?

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak, so simple... you were right!

Answer (score 4):

You need to trim the string, as it has invisible whitespace at the end in the form of a newline.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} service-redis', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    // here stdout has value "true"
    console.log(stdout.trimRight() === 'true')
});
```

Note that the trailing newline is not Node doing anything weird. It is generally the case that programs append a newline to their console output, particularly if a human will be looking at it. In fact, this is [one of the things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js) `console.log()` does for you.

Imagine using your terminal if the programs you use every day (`ls`, `git`, ...) terminated their output without a newline. Your prompt (the marker before where you type, e.g. `$`) would be crowded on the same line as the output from the last program. Yuck!

Even files usually end with a newline, as this [makes it easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline) to concatenate data together from various sources (e.g. log files) and work with UNIX tools. There is also a widely held practice to have your code editor enforce this for you. In short, you will see this all over the place.

The `childProcess.exec()` method does not make any assumptions about these newline conventions, it is too low-level for that, and so it keeps them in place. Issues of [tiny modules](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ama/issues/10) aside, you could easily create an abstraction on top of `exec()` that handles trimming for you.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I noticed that there's always a blank line printed after the value of `stdout`, so there's a `\n` at the end. Tnx!

Comment: No problem @Milkncookiez. I added some background and context that might be of interest to you.