# How to format errors to stdout in HAPI server?

Tags: exception, console, formatting, hapi.js

I need to reformat the console output from HAPI to spit out exceptions with the stack trace in a single line. Everything I come across looks like it's all about sending different info to the client, but I need to reformat the output going to stdout when an exception occurs.

I have tried adding a request-error handler and writing to console.log, and I see my formatted response, but the multi-line exception output still follows immediately afterward.

How do I format exception output?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `console.log(new Error('asdf'))` while watching stdout.

The stack trace should be included in that, but here's how to isolate it:

```js
    const test = new Error('test')
    console.log(test.stack)
```

I'm not running node right now or I would confirm my recommendations.

In addition, I believe `console.error()` writes to stderr.

Read these:

- [Difference between "process.stdout.write" and "console.log" in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js)
- https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

You could probably do something like this:

```js
const test = new Error('Detonations detected.')
console.log(`\n
    TIME: ${new Date().valueOf()}
    ERROR: ${test.message}
    STACK: ${test.stack}
`)
// Try this exactly as shown first so you can see
// how the template literal is operating.
```

Is that kind of what you are looking for? Hopefully, that is illustrative enough.

Comment: Maybe I interpretted this wrong. Are you trying to suppress the Hapi error output and put your own?