# can I test a javascript function using node.js

Tags: node.js

I suppose node.js allows us to test javascript code outside a browser. I am trying to test this function using node.js.

file print.js

```
var a = {
    someProperty: 1
}

function printObject(){
    process.stdout.write("hello: ",a);
}
```

When I try to run the above code as `node print.js`, nothing gets printed on the console. Why?

Comment: You are not calling the function. Just defining it.

Comment: You would have to call the function like `printObject()`. You have just declared the function

Comment: thanks. Happy to accept as an answer if one of you could change your comment into an answer.

Comment: [Also to this answer, you cannot `comma-separate` output.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534019/2569323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to call the function like `printObject()`. You have just declared the function