# What does process stdout connect do?

Tags: node.js

What does

```
process.stdout.connect({})
```

do and how can I use it?

Tryied googleing it but found nothing.
Tryied options but get error:

`TypeError: self._handle.connect is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdout) says, `process.stdout` returns a stream connected to stdout and that stream is of type `Socket`. Now, if you check the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#socketconnect) for `Socket` and look for the `connect` method you'll find that it initiates a connection on a given socket.

In order to use `process.stdout` you don't actually need to call `connect`, you can just write arbitrary strings to the stream which will get echoed in your stdout, e.g.

```
process.stdout.write("test"); // will print test to the console
```

But if logging to the console is your intent, it's probably easier to just use the provided `console.log()` which adds a lot of formatting and other stuff (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4976466/3761628) for further info).